# How to identify if brackets in the element are present or not using Java and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to write a code to identify if brackets are present or not in a given element in `Selenium-Webdriver`.

For example : the web element contain a number like `(235)` within the brackets. Then I need to check the brackets are present in that particular web element or not.

Comment: You can use **Contains** attribute to verify whether a text is present in a particular element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to use `Regex` to determine element text present with round brackets `()` as below :-

```
String regex = "\\(\\w+\\)"; //it will match any word present inside round brackets 

or

String regex = "\\(\\d+\\)"; //it will match only digits present inside round brackets
```

Use anyone of the `regex` expression to determine element text present inside round brackets `()` as:-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(..);
String text = el.getText();

if(text.matches(regex)) {
    //do your further stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("your_id_here)")); //or any other locating method
if(element.getText().contains("[") || element.getText().contains("]")) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Note: use `||` if only one of the opening or closing bracket should be present. If both of them are expected, use `&&`.